# background-image is not displayed in iphone

Tags: iphone, css, background, rendering, background-image

I don't know why the 'background-image' I set works fine in all browsers but it doesn't in Iphone's safari browser (wich is the one I need),

This is the relevant style for the question

```
    /**************************************************
        ESTILOS PARA SINGLE JOB
    **************************************************/


   /*Deleting all styles that dont take any effect with the question*/

    #panel.right ul.visible li a span.liLeft{
             width:95px;
             float:left;height:100%;display:block;
             position:relative;
             right:40px;
             /*HERE I INIT THE STYLE OF THE BACKGROUND IMAGE BUT I DONT SET THE URL*/
             -webkit-background-size: cover;
             -moz-background-size: cover;
             -o-background-size: cover;
             background-size: cover;
             z-index:10;
    }



    #panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight{
             background:black !important;
             color:#fff;

    }

    #panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight{
            z-index:9;
    }

    #panel.right ul.visible li#blue a{
            border-color:#0C7CC3;
    }
    #panel.right ul.visible li#pink a{
            border-color:#C21B7B;
    }
    #panel.right ul.visible li#orange a{
            border-color:#E83B35;
    }

    /*  HERE i set the urls for the different Id's and i can't see them in the iphone  */
    #panel.right ul.visible li#blue a span.liLeft{

            background-image:url('http://piscolabis.info/licht/img/azul.png');
    }
    #panel.right ul.visible li#pink  a span.liLeft{
            background-image:url(../img/rosa.png);
    }
    #panel.right ul.visible li#orange  a span.liLeft{
            background-image:url(../img/naranja.png);
    }


    /* deleting more styles*/
```

you can check the online code at http://jsfiddle.net/6dK3T/2/ or at http://piscolabis.info/job_single.html

As you can see i set a full path URL only so you can see that the image is in the server (and in any desktop browser), but i don't know why the image is still not displayed in the iphone

( it's displayed exactly like the other two i didn't set absolute path (and as they are not in jsdfiddle they don't work))

Is it because of the background-image? is it because the position:relative?

any idea why is this happening?

-EDIT-

should look like this

[image]

Isn't this like a mistery?

Comment: I looked at this on my Iphone, and I think the images are coming up. You should narrow your fiddle down to just the part that's giving you a problem.

Comment: well the place where the problem starts is in my question, can you see the red, blue and pink images in your phone? (the ones in the dark right navigation menu?) wouldn't your answer be a comment? :$

Comment: Sorry, probably should have been a comment - I'm new to this. Yes, I can see the red, blue, and pink images.

Comment: Dude thats weird. Have you checked the blue image in tje jsfiddle? (to compare. there should be 3 images on the dark navigatin menu, don't confuse it with the right borders)

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get it to show on my iPhone by tweaking your styles a bit :

```
#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liLeft{
     width:95px;
     float:left;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     margin-left: -40px;
     margin-right: 40px;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     z-index:10;
}



#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight {
     background:black !important;
     float: left;
     color:#fff;
}
```

The problem was the same with Safari on OSX. By removing the

```
 right: 40px;
```

in the CSS the images started showing.

http://jsfiddle.net/5sX54/9/

Comment: Tried you tweak, changing those properties in the CSS won't make them show in my iphone... are you sure?

Comment: This saved me--specifically, it was the background-size: cover;. I was having a weird issue where the background image was showing fine on desktop Safari, fine on desktop Chrome, fine on the iOS simulator, but wasn't showing on actual, physical devices. Adding background-size: cover; made it work everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with an image that was 2200x2500px but only 130kb and didn't load.
It seems like smartphones and tablet don't load images wider than 1024px.

So try to load a smaller image for specific devices and it should works OK.

Edit: I also removed the resizes on the image and the big image appeared. In my case I removed `background-size` (or put it to `auto`).

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment, I was pulling out my hair trying to figure out a wide background image.

Answer (score 1):

try giving an exact height to the `#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liLeft` element.
I modified your fiddle, added 90px instead of 100% and it seems working on my iphone:
http://jsfiddle.net/UGEyS/

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the same background image on the iphone? That looks like a pretty huge image, so it might be escaping the viewport somehow? I dont have an iphone to test with and this is a shot in the dark but you can maybe try to set your html to conform to the browsers viewport size with a meta tag, like this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

That or you can just use a media query to target a viewport smaller than something like 480px to use a different, smaller background image.

Comment: ahh, i was looking at the big background image :/